# What is the reason for Google SignInActivity failing to sign-in at stage 4 on Android

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin

I got an Android app which uses the newest version of Google Play Services API (9256000 / r31) and a user device log which indicates sign in failure after stage 4 of the SignInActivity. What is the reason for "SignInActivity: Sign in failed during 4"?

> 10-01 16:12:14.289  9603  9603 I SignInActivity: Transition from 3 to 4
>
> 10-01 16:12:14.289  2820  2939 D MotoNetwCtrlr: onReceive: intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE flg=0x10 (has extras) }
>
> 10-01 16:12:14.291  8457  8457 D CellBroadcastReceiver: subscriptionId = 1
>
> 10-01 16:12:14.302  9603  9603 W PopupManager: You have not specified a View to use as content view for popups. Falling back to the Activity content view. Note that this may not work as expected in multi-screen environments
>
> 10-01 16:12:14.304  8473  8473 I Mms     : Start transaction service, app version=4.4
>
> 10-01 16:12:14.321  4692  4703 W GamesServiceBroker: Client connected with SDK 8487000, Services 9683440, and Games 37240040
>
> 10-01 16:12:14.350  9603  9603 I SignInActivity: Transition from 4 to 11
>
> 10-01 16:12:14.351  9603  9603 W SignInActivity: onSignInFailed()...
>
> 10-01 16:12:14.351  9603  9603 W SignInActivity: Sign in failed during 4
>
> 10-01 16:12:14.351  9603  9603 W SignInActivity: ==> Returning non-OK result: 10002
>
> 10-01 16:12:14.351  9603  9603 W PopupManager: You have not specified a View to use as content view for popups. Falling back to the Activity content view. Note that this may not work as expected in multi-screen environments
>
> 10-01 16:12:14.385  4692  4753 W GamesServiceBroker: Client connected with SDK 8487000, Services 9683440, and Games 37240040
>
> 10-01 16:12:14.387  7567  7567 D Limbo-SaveGame: Java      ## Game services: onActivityResult(request = 9004, response = 10002, has intent)

Answer (score 0):

A similar case was logged in the [GPS issue tracker in GitHub](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1155) (though this particular is for GPS-Unity). They suggested the following that can help resolve the issue.

- Make sure the linked app section of the game contains the link to the Android app with matching bundle ID/package ID and SHA-1 fingerprint
- Sign the APK with your keystore (related above)

Hope this helps!

Comment: All this related to the app configuration in the store has been done long time ago. We upgraded the services recently and a few players are experiencing problems loging in or are being asked to log in multiple times. I need to know what the different stages of the sign in are so I can trouble-shoot our players problems and track errors in the app side of the code. It's confusing that so many different reasons for failing login all come back with the same response code and only the log has this scarse information on what's failing which means nothing to somebody sitting without the GPS code

Comment: In the use case of the above link it's failing at stage 8. Currently i need to know why it fails on stage 4.